# Expected value of the number times a head is followed by at least one head

Tags: probability, statistics

Can someone give a hint or the answer (with explanation) for the following question?

> What is the expected value of of the number times a head is followed by at least one head if a fair coin is tossed 30 times?

Comment: If the string is $HHH$ how many do you count?  I'd say two (the first two), yes?

Comment: Linearity of expectation.

Comment: @lulu I don't get it...

Comment: It's your problem.  I am asking you to evaluate the number you are asking for on a particular sequence.  I'd have said the possible answers were $1$ and $2$.  My answer would be $2$, but it's really up to you.

Comment: How does that help with a sequence of 30 times though?

Comment: Please just answer the question.  If we don't understand your definition, we can't hope to solve the problem.

Comment: Just to say, if your answer to my question is $2$ then the answer to the problem is $\frac {29}4$ by linearity.  If your answer is $1$ then the problem is a little harder.

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov  It can certainly be done by linearity, but it's harder to think through (I think).  It matters if you start with $T$ or $H$, for example.  At least the way I picture it.

Comment: I would say for $HHH$ we would have 2 heads which have 1 or more heads ahead of it.

Comment: Ok, so then the easy linearity argument works.  To get you started, let $X_i$ for $i\in \{1,\cdots, 29\}$ be the indicator variable for what you want.  So $X_i=1$ if both the $i^{th}$ and the $(i+1)^{st}$ tosses are $H$ and $0$ otherwise.  Then Linearity tells you that $E=E[\sum X_i]=\sum E[X_i]$.  Now just compute $E[X_i]$.

Comment: Everything makes sense now. Thanks!